# how to split geojson data in columns with spark sql scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have GeoJSON data as structtype like this:

```
root
 |-- features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- geometry: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- auswertezeit: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- geschwindigkeit: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- strecke_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- verkehrsstatus: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

and i will split data in Columns: strecke_id, auswertezeit, strecke_id, verkehrsstatus, geschwindigkeit and coordinates.
Thank you for your help

Comment: What version of Spark do you use? In 2.4 you have higher-order functions for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a bit simplified example, but this will give you the direction to adjust logic based on your own specs:

```
import sparkSession.implicits._

val geoDF = sparkSession.read.json("./src/test/resources/geo.json")

val resultDf = geoDF.withColumn("exploaded", functions.explode($"features"))
  .select("exploaded.properties.auswertezeit", "exploaded.properties.geschwindigkeit",
    "exploaded.properties.strecke_id", "exploaded.properties.verkehrsstatus")

resultDf.show()
resultDf.printSchema()
```

Input data (formatted):

```
{
    "features": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "auswertezeit": "x",
                "geschwindigkeit": 1,
                "strecke_id": 11,
                "verkehrsstatus": "xx"
            }
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "auswertezeit": "y",
                "geschwindigkeit": 2,
                "strecke_id": 22,
                "verkehrsstatus": "yy"
            }
        }
    ],
    "type": "xyz"
}
```

Result:

```
+------------+---------------+----------+--------------+
|auswertezeit|geschwindigkeit|strecke_id|verkehrsstatus|
+------------+---------------+----------+--------------+
|           x|              1|        11|            xx|
|           y|              2|        22|            yy|
+------------+---------------+----------+--------------+

root
 |-- auswertezeit: string (nullable = true)
 |-- geschwindigkeit: long (nullable = true)
 |-- strecke_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- verkehrsstatus: string (nullable = true)
```